# Virtualenv does not point to correct python3

Tags: python, virtualenv, setup.py

With a bash script I have created a virtual environment for my project, the bash script is kept in the same directory as the project:

```
#!/bin/bash

virtualenv=~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv.py
wd=$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")
env_dir=~/virtual_environments/invest_scripts
$virtualenv $env_dir

cd -- "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"
source $env_dir/bin/activate
sudo python3 setup.py develop
deactivate
```

After running the script, I activate the environment using

```
source ~/virtual_environments/invest_scripts/bin/activate
```

But I get the following outputs

```
(invest_scripts) $which python
(invest_scripts) $/Users/name/virtual_environments/invest_scripts/bin/python
(invest_scripts) $which python3
(invest_scripts) $/usr/bin/python3
```

---

Additionally I found that when I open the interactive `python3` shell when the virtual environment is not activated, and import a package which was specified in `setup.py`. The file points to the egg shown from my project.

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Nov 15 2019, 04:04:52) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__file__
'/Users/name/invest_scripts/.eggs/numpy-1.18.0-py3.7-macosx-10.7 x86_64.egg/numpy/__init__.py'
```

Could someone explain what is happening?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to run `setup.py develop` in the first place? That's rarely a good idea.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [How to make \`sudo\` preserve $PATH?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191)

Comment: @MartijnPieters because I did not have write permissions to the folder when running that command

Comment: To what folder? In the virtualenv? Did you run a `sudo` command connected to that virtualenv before? Just `sudo chown -R yourusername virtualenv` to fix that. Don't compound the situation!

Comment: To `/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/`, I have not run any `sudo` connected to virtualenv before

Comment: That would indicate you were not using the virtualenv Python to install your package. When using the virtualenv python `setup.py install` should not be writing to `/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/` *at all*.

Comment: Frankly, you don't need `activate` at all if you know the virtualenv's path anyway; you can just prefix all executables with `${virtualenv_path}/bin/`. Most of what `activate` does is setting `PATH`; it's sort of convenient for local development, but not nearly as useful in a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` executes commands using a new shell, it won't copy across the `PATH` environment variable. This is not problem specific to `virtualenv`s. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path for the generic solution to this.

However, you don't need to rely on shell executable resolution. Activating a virtualenv essentially just sets your `PATH` variable so that your shell finds `$env_dir/bin/python` first when you use the unqualified `python` executable. You can just use the full path of the `$env_dir/bin/python` executable and so completely sidestep executable lookups:

```sh
sudo $env_dir/bin/python setup.py install
```

However, you generally want to avoid switching users when installing packages into a virtualenv, especially root. There should not be any need to. If you have permission issues *in your virtualenv* then you have used `sudo` in the past with it, and you don't want to compound that issue. In that case *repair your virtualenv permissions* by recursively re-assigning the files to your own account: `` sudo chown -R $UID:`id -g` $env_dir ``.

Next, rather than use `setup.py install`, use `pip` to do the installing. Just use the `pip` command in the virtualenv point it to the directory containing the `setup.py` file. If that's the current directory, use:

```sh
$env_dir/bin/pip .
```